# How to resize a partition on a dynamic disk on Windows Server 2003?

Tags: partitioning, windows-server

The Disk Management tool on Windows Server 2003 won't let me expand a partition because it contains the system and boot drive.

How can I expand this partition without third party application?

Note: I tried all sorts of "free" partition managers, but they are all paid versions on Windows Server. Plus, the real free ones are not compatible with dynamic drivers.

Answer (score 0):

With your requirement of *not* using 3rd party applications, you are out of luck.

See the restrictions on dynamic drives [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/225551/en-us).